# Bandwidth selection for kernel density estimation, using a Weibull kernel

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Let $\{s_1,\ldots,s_N\}$ be a collection of N samples. 
I have performed the kernel density estimation using the classical form:
$$
\hat{f}(x) = \frac{1}{Nh}\sum_{i=1}^N  K\left(\frac{x-s_i}{h}\right)
$$
where $K\left(\frac{x-s_i}{h}\right)$ is computed as a Weibull kernel, with $k=1$ and $\lambda=1$.

My question is: which is the easiest way to compute the bandwidth $h$? I am using the sample standard deviation, but it seems to be too small, i.e., the computed PDF appears too noisy at the end.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could probably try to use the "rule-of-thumb" for density estimation based on the sample size and the standard deviation:
$$1.06\sigma n^{-\frac{1}{5}}$$

There are several other methods, which do not depend on the chosen kernell. One popular is the cross-validation. You may check the chapter 5 in Wand and Jones "Kernel smoothing" and references therein.

Comment: Does it work also for other distributions that are different from the Gaussian one?

Comment: As far as I understand it does not require that the distribution is Gaussian. In that case we are not nonparametric anymore. The assumption is that we use an estimate of the second derivative of the Gaussian density in the bandwidth selection. In other words we can estimate any density (including non Gaussian).

Comment: Have you checked if this "rule-of-thumb" works for you?

Comment: Yes I did, and this is what I got: http://cl.ly/2s361r0C3T3o Thus, I cannot understand whether this "noise" on the curve is coming from the bandwidth estimation or not. I guess yes.

Comment: May I ask what is the motivation of using the Weibull kernel?

Comment: Because I tried to use the gaussian kernel, however the underlying distributions are asymmetric, and thus the gaussian kernel was not performing well. Consequently, I decided to use a non-symmetric kernel.

Comment: Then, how can one answer to the need of approximate an asymmetric function?

Comment: My guess is that your noise is due to the innapropriately selected kernel. I would suggest using the Epanechnikov kernel and the "rule-of-thumb" bandwidth. It will estimate any sufficiently smooth density (including asymetric ones). Which software do you use?

Comment: I use MATLAB. I'll try to change the kernel, then.

Comment: You might also check R and the package: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/np/index.html which has a lot of nonparameric functionality or the simple function density(x). Also your question would probalby fit more discussions on http://stats.stackexchange.com/